# Communications between Blender and Tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, blender, reinforcement-learning

I have a simulation inside Blender that I would like to control externally using the TensorFlow library. The complete process would go something like this:

```
while True:
    state = observation_from_blender()
    action = find_action_using_tensorflow_neural_net(state)
    take_action_inside_blender(action)
```

I don't have much experience with the threading or subprocess modules and so am unsure as to how I should go about actually building something like this.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than mess around with Tensorflow connections and APIs, I'd suggest you take a look at the Open AI Universe Starter Agent[1]. The advantage here is that as long as you have a VNC session open, you can connect a TF based system to do reinforcement learning on your actions.

Once you have a model constructed via this, you can focus on actually building a lower level API system for the two things to talk to each other.

[1] https://github.com/openai/universe-starter-agent

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, trying to get Universe working with my current setup was a bit of a pain. I'm also on a fairly tight deadline so I just needed something that worked straight away.

I did find a somewhat DIY solution that worked well for my situation using the pickle module. I don't really know how to convert this approach into proper pseudocode, so here is the general outline:

```
Process 1 - TensorFlow:
    load up TF graph
    wait until pickled state arrives

while not terminated:

    Process 2 - Blender: 
        run simulation until next action required
        pickle state
        wait until pickled action arrives

    Process 1 - TensorFlow:
        unpickle state
        feedforward state through neural net, find action
        pickle action
        wait until next pickled state arrives

    Process 2 - Blender:
        unpickle action
        take action
```

This approach worked well for me, but I imagine there are more elegant low level solutions. I'd be curious to hear of any other possible approaches that achieve the same goal.

Answer (score 0):

I did this to install tensorflow with the python version that comes bundled with blender.

- Blender version: 2.78
- Python version: 3.5.2

  1. First of all you need to install pip for blender's python. For that I followed instructions mentioned in this link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56011/how-to-use-pip-with-blenders-bundled-python. (What I did was drag the python3.5m icon into the terminal and then further type the command '~/get-pip.py').
  2. Once you have pip installed you are all set up to install 3rd party modules and use them with blender.
  3. Navigate to the bin folder insider '/home/path to blender/2.78/' directory. To install tensorflow, drag the python3.5m icon into terminal, then drag pip3 icon into terminal and give the command install tensorflow.
  4. I got an error mentioning module lib2to3 not found. Even installing the module didn't help as I got the message that no such module exists. Fortunately, I have python 3.5.2 installed on my machine. So navigate to  /usr/lib/python3.5 and copy the lib2to3 folder from there to /home/user/blender/2.78/python/lib/python3.5 and then again run the installation command for tensorflow. The installation should complete without any errors. Make sure that you test the installation by importing tensorflow.